# Elastic search: Like query not working in string contains &(ampersand)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query which is not working. I think the searched value containing & (ampersand) symbol. I am talking about the following query.

```
GET "path"_search
{

  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(Department_3037.Department_3037_analyzed:*P&C*)"
    }    
  }
}
```

Why this query is not working and how to overcome this issue or i need like query of string containing & like (p&c) ,l&t etc...
Let me know how this can be fixed..
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a field that stores the string . `(Department_3037.Department_3037_analyzed:*P&C*)`. Is that `analyzed` or `not_analyzed`.

Comment: yes, I have field that stores the string. Also we are used the default value of index (analyzed index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the field you are searching in is `analyzed`. If the field contains the text `(Department_3037.Department_3037_analyzed:*P&C*)` , this will be tokenized as : `Department_3037` , `Department_3037_analyzed` , `P` , `C`.

You can get this using :

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=standard" -d "(Department_3037.Department_3037_analyzed:*P&C*)"
```

You will get the tokens as follows:

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"Department_3037","start_offset":1,"end_offset":16,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},

{"token":"Department_3037_analyzed","start_offset":17,"end_offset":41,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":2},

{"token":"P","start_offset":43,"end_offset":44,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":3},

{"token":"C","start_offset":45,"end_offset":46,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":4}]}.
```

If you want to retrieve the documents you will have to escape the special characters :

```
{
"query": {
   "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "\\(Department_3037\\.Department_3037_analyzed\\:\\*P\\&C\\*\\)"
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This not my requirement. It takes all the value contains p and c. I need "like" query results.

Comment: you will get `like` query results if you remove all special characters.

Comment: In my value string contains special characters.

Comment: You will have to escape them. They are not there in the `reverse index` as shown in my answer . And you can search the text which is there in `reverse index`.

Comment: Removed special character from p&c  but got empty result

Comment: "_source": {
               
               "Branch_3037": "Milwaukee WI",
               "Department_3037": "P&C",
               
            } This is my json in the elastic index. How to get the p&c dept using LIKE query.

Comment: {
"query": {
   "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "\\(Department_3037\\.Department_3037_analyzed\\:\\*P\\&C\\*\\)"
    }
   }
 } its works fine. I got results.thank you! But found another problem with normal text. for example:  i have a string like "Hays Company" i searched in "ays" get empty result. search "hays" it will works fine. Why?

Comment: use *ays. It will search hays. this is because there is not text with `ays` in reverse index.

Comment: This is my string "Hays Company", it contains "ays" but not works

Comment: In `sql` too , you will search it like %ays%. Same is here. Here * is used.

Comment: "query_string": {
        "default_field": "Division_3037.Division_3037_analyzed",
      "query": "\\(Division_3037.Division_3037_analyzed\\:\\*ays\\*\\)"
      
    }    

This is my query. But it shows "no records"

Comment: `Division_3037.Division_3037_analyzed` is a field in side your index or text inside your field . Its quite unclear. Please show a sample document??

Comment: "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.1336336,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "nameOfIndex",
            "_type": "testData",
            "_id": "wweqe-fdfds",
            "_score": 1.1336336,
            "_source": {
               "Reveid_3037": 100,
                          
               "Division_3037": "Test Data",               
               "Department_3037": "L&T"
               
            }
         }
} This is my Elastic data. I need Department_3037(Searched Value:"L&T") and Division_3037(Searched Value:"est") using LIKE query?

Comment: Your above is correct in case of "L&T"  its not works in case of "est"

Comment: it works for "L&T" because here & is working as `AND` operator not the text '&' . For est you will have to add `*` operator.